# Authenticate login screen without session factory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, maven

I am using Spring, Maven and Hibernate.
I have this login page with a username and password. I am trying to authenticate the client to make sure he/she is using a correct username and password from the database. When the user hits submit, the page gets render to localhost:8080/Login/login with a 404 Error. I want to be able to render results on the main page.

I am not quiet sure how this form action works. Here is what my JSP looks like

```
<form  action = "login" id="login" method="post">


    Username<input type="text" id="text" /> <br>
    Password<input type="text" id="text" /> <br>

    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />

</form>
```

This is my service dao layer:
@Service
public class LoginService{

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Transactional
public List<tbl_login> getUsers() {
    List<tbl_login> userList = new ArrayList<tbl_login>();
    try {

        userList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(tbl_login.class).list();

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userList;
```

And lastly, this is my controller:
{

@Controller
public class LoginController

```
LoginService loginService = (LoginService) ServiceLocator.getInstance()
        .findService("loginService");

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@RequestParam(value = "username") String username,
        @RequestParam(value = "password") String password, Locale locale,
        Model model) {

    List<tbl_login> login = loginService.getUsers();
    for (tbl_login tbl_login : login) {
        if (tbl_login.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
            if (tbl_login.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                model.addAttribute("username", username);
            }
        }
    }
    return "/";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your current code:

1. there is no method bound to this URL: `/login` (your form action goes there)
   You should change your controller method to `@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)`
2. I'd recommend using @Autowired on top of `loginService` instead of `"ServiceLocator.getInstance()...."`
3. I'm not sure whether sessionFactory will get injected (I'm not seeing any anotation on it, but maybe you didn't post it)
4. I recommend using `<form:form>` instead of `<form>` so that in the future you'd be able to take advantage of spring features.
5. `Username<input type="text" id="text" />` should be changed to `Username<input type="text" name="username" id="text" />` (and password too - so that the controller recognizes them)

Start with this, and debug your way up from there.

Good luck!